# How to login using FaceBook test users (created from the facebook developer app roles page)

Tags: facebook, canvas, authentication, passwords

Is it possible to login to facebook directly (facebook.com) using the test user account created using the Facebook Developer app feature (Roles / Create test users)? What password should I use? I understand we can use the "Switch to " option after logging in as myself to facebook, but I want to be able to login directly using the test user accounts, so that I can provide these user details for other testers who do need to use their personal facebook account in any way related to the testing of the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply change the password of the Test User by issuing a POST request to this URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_USER_ID?password=NEW_PASSWORD&name=NEW_NAME&method=post&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Then you can give other people the account info of that user with the newly set password and they can log in to Facebook as that user.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm.  In case anyone else come looking for more details, I first logged in as myself to Facebook then did a switch to the test user and then accessed my canvas app , looked at my application log file where I log the oauth token (for the new request from the test user)  and then used that as the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN in the above post method.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, we can login directly facebook(facebook.com) with test user accounts.

**Step 1**

Create test user by clicking **Add** button

[image: Add user screenshot]

**Step 2**

Click **Edit** button where have all option

- Change name
- Set Password
- Generate access token etc.

[image: Edit user screenshot]

Comment: It's should have a default password, such a pain to change each user password. And right now we are facing issues in our company dashboard preventing us to change password.